# dynamically update dates in date picker in Jquery AJAX call

Tags: c#, jquery, model-view-controller, datepicker

I have Location text box auto complete text box, and AvailableDates textbox.

when user typing Location my autocomplete textbox has a AJAX call to get matching record. On autocomplete's onSelect call, I will get Id and I have to call MVC control's action to get date base on that Id. In the AvailableDates textbox should a datepicker attach and it should disable all the dates sent my control's action.

How can I achieve this, any help will be appreciated!

Thanks.

I tried following code but it is not disabling the dates.

```
var Locations = [
   { value: 'Andorra', id: 'AD' },
   // ...
   { value: 'Zimbabwe', id: 'ZZ' }
];

$('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
    lookup: Locations,
    onSelect: function (suggestion) {
        alert('You selected: ' + suggestion.value + ', ' + suggestion.id);
$.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("getAvailableDates","booking")',
        dataType: "json",
        type: "GET",            
        cache: false,
        data: {id:suggestion.id} ,
        success: function (holidays) { 
            if (data.success) {
                alert(data.message);
                  $('#txtAvailableDates').datepicker({
                   beforeShowDay: function(date){

                  }
              });
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
    }
});
```

MVC controller action to return List holiday dates

date textbox should be populated with dates, disabling holiday dates.

Comment: what is the controller returning? can you post what is in data?

Comment: public ActionResult getAvailableDates(string id)
{
   
    var itemList = (from items in xxx where yyy select new { holidays = ppp }).ToList();

    return Json(itemList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

Comment: so can you show the json in data. put a console.log(data) in your success method and post the json as part of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is how I got it working.
my not exactly sure what your controller is returning but mine returns an array of dates.
yours is obviously using the id but for my example I'm just returning an array of dates.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[Produces("application/json")]
[ApiController]
public class BookingController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public IActionResult Get(string id)
    {
        DateTime[] holidays = new DateTime[]
            { 
                new DateTime(2019, 10, 14),
                new DateTime(2019, 11, 11),
                new DateTime(2019, 11, 28),
            };
        return Ok(holidays);
    }
    }        
}
```

then in the ajax call on success I use map to get the date to match the datepicker string.  and used beforeShowDay to disable the holidays

```
 $.ajax({
        url: 'api/Booking/AP',
        dataType: "json",
        type: "GET",            
        cache: false,
            success: function (data) { 
               var dates = data.map(x => new Date(x).toISOString().split('T')[0]);
                console.log(dates);
                $("#datepicker").datepicker({
                     beforeShowDay: function(date){
                        var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
                        console.log(string);
                         return [ dates.indexOf(string) == -1 ]
                    }
                })
            },
        error: function (xhr) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
        });
```

Comment: thanks @Bryan. how to convert List<DateTime> to have only dates?

Comment: I tried list.select(x=>x.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")).Tolist() but this keep returning date with time.

Comment: that is what that map function does in the javascript.  data was an array of datetime (serialized to javascript) the map function in the ajax call turn it into just date.

Comment: for me this is not API controller, its MVC application. how can i return array? after AJAX get call, and executing controller's Get method, it is directly going to error function of AJAX call.

Comment: Shouldnt matter they both return json. But i notice in your ajax call you call the result holidays but then reference data which does not exist

Comment: Set the success up like i have it

Comment: ok...i resolved this. need to add Json Behavior return Json(holidays, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);